# Getting Instance of the whole JS file in order to use in android webview

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

There is a js file in my directory that I need the whole instance. Actually I'm pretty new on Javascript.

```
<HTML>
<script>
var anObject= new blabla("MyJsFile.js");
// Do the rest

</script>

<body></body>
</html>
```

HTML file and JS file in same directory so this works on Chrome or any other mobile web browser but android webview. It looks like I need to get instance of the whole js file with other way because It doesnt work on android WebView. Gives error: Undefined blabla. Looks like other web browsers doing some work to understand that definition.

Comment: That's because you do not have blabla function in javascript have you?? Actually all of them are throwing the error but still rendering your HTML code so that atleast you see the page but android does not do that as it would no more be your html page but an application

Comment: What do you mean by "getting an instance of a js file"?

Comment: eddiela.github.io/BarcodeReader/demo.html you can view source at line 50-51-52 ... whole instance of a js file.